# Line 348: Char 17: runtime error: downcast of misaligned address 0x7ffe52341919 for type 'const _Rb_tree_node<int>', which requires 8 byte alignmzzzzz

Tags: c++17

Line 348: Char 17: runtime error: downcast of misaligned address 0x7ffe52341919 for type 'const _Rb_tree_node', which requires 8 byte alignment (stl_tree.h)
0x7ffe52341919: note: pointer points here
7f 00 00  00 00 00 00 20 60 00 00  10 08 00 00 40 60 00 00  50 08 00 00 40 60 00 00  10 08 00 00 40
^
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_tree.h:357:17

class Solution {
public:
int minimumSeconds(vector& nums) {
int n=nums.size();

```
    set<int> st;
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++) {
        st.insert(nums[i]);
    }
    if (st.size() == 1) {
        return 0;
    }
    vector<int> v(10, 0);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int prev = nums[(i - 1 + n) % n];
        int curr = nums[i];
        int next = nums[(i + 1) % n];
        
        set<int> st = {prev, curr, next};
        
        for (int num : st) {
            v[num]++;
        }
    }

    int res = *max_element(v.begin(), v.end());
    int x = n - res;
    return x + 1;
}
```

};

remove error from the code i have provided

Comment: What have you tried? And can you provide an explanation for what result you expect?

Comment: [The problem statement](https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-seconds-to-equalize-a-circular-array/description/) says elements of `nums` can be as large as `10^5`. But vector `v` only contains 10 elements. `v[num]++;` very likely exhibits undefined behavior by way of accessing an index out of bounds. In other words, you are scribbling all over the heap memory.